# Check, if one Line Segment intersects with a set of line segments

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, numpy, cython

I have a a line segment `AB` (2d) from point `A` to point `B`. For the representation of a `coastline` (closed polygon, 3*10^3 vertices), I have a `NumPy` array (2d) of points which start and end at the same point. I want to know, if the connection between point `A` and `B` intersects the coastline.

My first approach was to iterate over each line segment of the closed polygon and check if it intersects with `AB`. Here is [the underlying method](http://%20https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/).

Even if I do this working with `NumPy` arrays or translating the function with `cython`, it is not fast enough, because I have to do it a lot of times for different `A`s and `B`s.

I thought, this may be a conceptual problem and I was wondering, if there is a smarter way to check only, if at least one intersection exists (`True`/`False`)?

I tried to use `shapely` as well. But this was kind of slow.

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
import numpy as np

coastline = LineString(np.dstack(x_values,y_values))

def intersection(A,B,Coastline):

      AB = LineString([(A[0], A[1]), (B[0], B[1])])
      if AB.intersection(coastline).is_empty:
         return False
      return True
```

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227423/how-to-efficiently-determine-which-of-thousands-of-polygons-intersect-with-a-lin

Comment: So what are your expectations? Don't be so vague: How much time does it takes now and how much faster would be Ok?

Comment: Is your problem ACTUALLY just one line segment or will you check for more line segments? The answer may depend on that, because then it may be worthwile to do something to the coastline segments like indexing or whatnot.

Comment: According to Robert Kerns Line Profiler, the function I created in numpy-array way takes 1583.7 * 10 ^-6 s per Hit (5788 calls).

Comment: There are many posts about polygon intersection with segments, try checking those. Regardless of your method, as you have many vertices on your polygon, it might be good to make a less detailed polygon with less vertices, such that we can test the line against this new polygon. It needs to be generated such that if they intersect, you will need to check with the actual detailed one, but if they do not, you can know it does not intersect the detailed one either

Comment: I have to check 1 Linesegment against all the coastline-segments very often (+ 10^6 times). The coastline-segments do not change, but AB is altered and can not be collected in an array, because it is determined dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a collision detection problem.

So in your case the best is to put your coastline inside one spatial datastrcture such as bsp-tree, quad-tree, aabb-tree, etc.

Then perform intersection between your line segment and the tree-structure.

See for instance CGAL AABB_tree:
https://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/index.html

That library is for 3D but the same idea works for 2D. You can embedd almost any geometry inside aabbtree and query line intersection very fast