# Is there a better than O(N^2) algorithm for testing if a set of N line segments intersect in 3-space?

Tags: algorithm, 3d, geometry, computational-geometry, intersection

I have a set of N line segments in 3-space where each segment is represented by two coordinates denoting the endpoints of the segment:
(x1, y1, z1)-(x2, y2, z2)

I want to know if any line segments are touching, or more formally, if they are:

- intersecting
- partially or fully overlapping

**Of course there is the naive search of testing each one against the other in O(N^2) with 2 nested loops, but is there a more efficient algorithm?**

Co-linear lines are ok so long as they do not overlap; touching at exactly at the endpoints is acceptable.  (This is a sanity for [NEC2](https://www.nec2.org/) because it does not handle wires that touch unless they connect at endpoints.  Any that touch but do not touch at endpoints must be broken into multiple wires.)

Comment: Are these half-lines/closed lines or are the lines stretched infinitely?

Comment: @user1984, they are line segments.   (x1, y1, z1)-(x2, y2, z2) are endpoints.  I updated the question.

Comment: using BVH or any spatial subdivision will lead to lower complexity see  https://stackoverflow.com/q/18512815/2521214

Comment: I believe you can use a BVH tree structure to check the intersection of a line against a set of lines, that is a O(log N) search. E.g., check answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51897251/check-if-one-line-segment-intersects-with-a-set-of-line-segments/51903195#51903195 then you can check all lines against the other lines in O(N log N) where N is the number of lines.

Comment: As a rule, line segments do not intersect in 3D. If you have specific reasons to believe that they do in your case, you should state them.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, user error could make it possible.  This is for a sanity check to warn the user to fix their NEC code.

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks.

Comment: A possible solution is to run an efficient 2D intersection algorithm on a projection of the segments (say onto XY), and check existence of true 3D intersections. Bentley-Ottman takes time O((n+k) log n). Unfortunately, in the projection, k will be larger than needs be.